# Redirect win32 cursor events to another HWND

Tags: c++, c, winapi

I am attempting to implement a means by which a window can be displayed as if it were a child in another window of which it is not a child, basically by displaying the content of that window as a bitmap within the pseudo-parent window. Part of the rationale behind doing this instead of just making the second window a proper child is so that it can be worked into graphics processing like OpenGL and be manipulated as if it were just another texture. My current approach is to hide the pseudo-child, and when the pseudo-parent receives `WM_PAINT`, temporarily show the psuedochild off-screen and put its contents into a bitmap with `PrintWindow`, and display that. This way, the bitmap could also be used for a texture in the future. Now, is it possible to redirect or forward cursor events that occur within the region to which the psuedochild is painted to the actual pseudochild, e.g. so if it contains a button, the user can press it?

My first thought was to just send a `WM_xxxx` event to the pseudochild, but this will not effect its children windows. I believe `SendInput` actually moves the cursor to the specified physical location, which is not desired, and I am unsure if it can reliably work with off-screen coordinates. I also tried modifying `WM_NCHITTEST` so that the psuedoparent returns `HTNOWHERE` when the cursor is over the region where the psuedochild is drawn, and the psuedochild translates its `lParam` to the on-screen position of where it is actually drawn and then passes the translated coordinate to `DefWindowProc`; however, it seems the pseudochild never receives the `WM_NCHITTEST` when the cursor is over where it is drawn.

Comment: That's an idea that reads "horrible" in one bazillion dimensions. Why don't you just host your OpenGL-rendered content right where you want it? It's not like the `WS_EX_NOREDIRECTIONBITMAP` extended window style was invented without a proper use case...

Comment: As for the technical restraints you're operating under, you can't do what you're intending to: [Replaying input is not the same as reprocessing it](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20121206-00/?p=5903). If you value your time, stop sinking any down that route.

Comment: @IInspectable: He's not redirecting an OpenGL rendering into a host window (which as you say, could simply be rendered in the correct place).  He's redirecting rendering of ordinary USER32 window hierarchies into an OpenGL rendering.  Think of the famous (infamous?) WPF tricks with textboxes and scrollbars placed on the sides of a spinning cube

Comment: @BenVoigt Famous or infamous, it can't be done. Qt has tried, and the results are apparent for anyone to see. You can continue pouring millions into that sinkhole, or just acknowledge that fighting the system won't have the challenger come out as the winner.

Comment: @IInspectable, alright, so what would be a better approach to render/interact with something that already exists as win32 window(s) within OpenGL rendering? Analogous approaches are apparently possible on other platforms using their native UI elements